# Create assignment executable script

Tags: linux, unix

Whats going on so for my unix/linux class the teacher wants us to create a create_assignment executable to use for all of our work or he takes off points. I have been trying for a week now and asked the teacher twice and it hasn't helped at all. so when I type ./create_assignment assignment3 it is suppose to make assignment 3 with a header I know I'm suppose to use chmod +x create_assignment to make it executable. I got it to make a create_assignment executable one time but it wouldnt do anything so I need to be shown how to make it executable and make it create the new assignment, I can post pictures if needed.

Comment: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you tried chmod u+x  to make it executable?

Comment: Yeah I have I just checked my home directory and my create_assignment file is executable but when I do ./create_assignment assignment3 it doesnt do anything when it should create the assignment and add my header to it

Answer (score 0):

Please share the code of your script. Have you checked file permissions? What user is running the job, and does that user own the destination folder/file?